# Как заполнить foreign key mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

у меня есть таблица Form(по типу чека) связаная с таблицами Book,Worker,Reader, нужно заполнить foreign key(idBook,idWorker,idReader) в таблице Form, столбец kod думал сделать,как код в котором первая цифра соответствует idBook, вторая idWorker, третья idReader) Подскажите,пожалуйста, как можно это реализовать?

[image: Таблица Form]

Comment: С чем возникли сложности? С написанием INSERT запроса?

Comment: не могу написать правильно insert запрос

Comment: В настоящее время связи между записями таблиц нет. Никакой запрос не может высосать их из пальца. Задача не решается. Если  же определяемая связь имеется - показывайте её (DDL таблиц + пример наполнения + объяснение, где и как определить связь). PS. А фотографию выбросите - мы по ним не лечим.